# Can the Camera Module for Raspberry Pi Zero be used in Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspicam

I wonder if this camera [Camera Module for Raspberry Pi Zero](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/raspberry-pi-zero-camera-module#shopify-product-reviews) also works with the Raspberry Pi 3? 
I could not find any information about its compatibility to other RPi models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this particular camera module can't be used with Raspberry Pi 3.

While the camera hardware itself would work, the ribbon cable is of a different size and won't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Camera's flex cable is less wide in RPi 1 than in RPi 3, so You ( and also I ) can not use same camera in both models.

Comment: It's the same camera only the cable is different.